# jQuery - Set datepicker's container to a specific div

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, datepicker

I'm using jQuery UI datepicker on an div. the div hides and shows by moving mouse. as the datepicker are exist at the end of the `<body>` tag, not inside my div, the div disappears when I move the mouse to the datepicker.

I loaded the datepicker like this:

**Javascript**

```
$("#dt1").datepicker({
    dateFormat: "dd/mm/yy",
    showOn: "button",
    buttomText: "Arrival date",
    buttonImage: "<button location>",
    buttonImageOnly: true,
});
```

**HTML**

```
<input type="text" id="dt1" size="10" name="dt1" value="Arrival Date" />
```

How can I set the container of the datepicker to a specific div?

**Edit:** See it on JSFiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/G4NzC/

Comment: Suggest you create a demo in jsfiddle.net for others to better understand problem.

Comment: Added. http://jsfiddle.net/G4NzC/

Comment: you don't need the onclick event in your code

Comment: thank you I'll change that. but this is not solving the problem anyway

Comment: i didn't say that its the solution. just pointed a mistake

Comment: this kinda works, but you have to move the mouse quick and the styling is messed up, but hey the idea might help, here is the link http://jsfiddle.net/h59jq/

Answer (score 10, accepted):

The solution is to move the dataPicker's div to inside the hidden-absolute-positioned-div.

something like this (this is just the idea by @andrew but you need to improve css styling and other things):

Note that `#dt1` is the input text for the date, `#ui-datepicker-div` is the datepicker's div and `#bookingBox` is the hidden-absolute-positioned-div.

```
$("#dt1").datepicker({ 
dateFormat: "dd/mm/yy", 
showOn: "button", 
buttomText: "Arrival date",
buttonImage: "http://www.inbar.co.il/designFiles/Inbar_Ico_Calander.png", 
buttonImageOnly: true,
beforeShow:function(textbox, instance){
    $('#ui-datepicker-div').css({
        position: 'absolute',
        top:-20,
        left:5                   
    });
    $('#bookingBox').append($('#ui-datepicker-div'));
    $('#ui-datepicker-div').hide();
} });
```

Answer (score 4):

Simplest solution which I've found is

```
$("#myDatePicker").datepicker({
   beforeShow:function(textbox, instance){
     $('.DivToAppendPicker').append($('#ui-datepicker-div'));
   }
});
```

Comment: This was what I needed to get the datepicker to display properly in a bootstrap 5 modal.  My system will display content in a modal, and also allow you to break it out to it's own browser tab.  So I had to check and see if it was in a modal, then append it to the .modal-content div, otherwise append it to the <body>