# jquery DateTimePicker on scrollable div

Tags: javascript, jquery, scroll, datepicker, position

I'm using this jquery plugin for a dateTimePicker: http://xdsoft.net/jqplugins/datetimepicker/

It works fine but there is a problem with displaying it in a scrollable div/content.

The position isn't fixed to the input anymore. It is fixed to the HTML surrounded and it will stay where it is after scrolling.
[image]

The second problem is that the calendar is overlapping the "red line" on the bottom. In my case this represents the browser bottom and therefore it would cut the calendar and it's not usable anymore.

The plugin supports to appear above the input if the content below is to small but not in this case.

Does anybody have an idea how to solve this issue?
The documentation of the plugin has some iFrame support but i cant see a way using this for my specific problem.

Example Page: http://heymark.de/test/test.html

Regards!

Comment: provide a working example that demonstrates the problem (not an image...)

Comment: Here you go: http://heymark.de/test/test.html

Comment: Possible duplicate of [jQuery - Set datepicker's container to a specific div](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23721957/jquery-set-datepickers-container-to-a-specific-div)

Comment: This answer belongs to the jquery UI datepicker. The idea seems to be correct tho but i dont see it working in my case.

Comment: It's exactly the same. The `datetimepicker` set the element in the `body` (and not inside your container). If you want to to not get out of the red-bordered-box - it must be inside that container...

Comment: I updated my example. It is working correct with jqueryUI Datepicker as you said. But still with the different plugin i dont see any way how to do it since there is no "beforeShow" function.

Comment: This specific plugin has the `onGenerate` callback. Try to use it.

Comment: Thank you very much, this helped a lot. Some strange positioning issues right now but i can handle that. Thanks for your help!

Comment: I also got the positioning issues and didn't have the time to check it out. Did you manage to fix it? It will be nice to see the solution :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Took some time and digging in the source (It's always a shame that developers don't give a complete set of callbacks!).

I used the `afterOpen.xdsoft` event (which is not documented, and used internally, so I guess you can't rely on it to work in future versions).

But in this example it works:

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  $('#datetimepicker1').datetimepicker({ 
    onShow: function() {
      $('#content').append(this)
    }
  })
  $('#datetimepicker2').datetimepicker({ 
    onShow: function() {
      $('#content').append(this)
    }
  })
  $(document).on('afterOpen.xdsoft', function(event) {
    $(event.target).position({
      my: 'left top',
      at: 'left bottom',
      of: $(event.target).data('input')
    })
  });


  $("#dt1").datepicker({ 
    dateFormat: "dd/mm/yy", 
    buttomText: "Arrival date",
    buttonImageOnly: true,
    beforeShow:function(textbox, instance){
      $('#ui-datepicker-div').css({
        position: 'absolute',
        top:-20,
        left:5                   
      });
      $('#content').append($('#ui-datepicker-div'));
      $('#ui-datepicker-div').hide();
    } });

});
```

```css
#content {
  background: #fff;
  height: 500px;
  width: 500px;
  position: relative;
  overflow: scroll;
  border: 2px solid red;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="http://code.jquery.com/ui/1.12.0/jquery-ui.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery-datetimepicker/2.5.4/build/jquery.datetimepicker.full.min.js"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery-datetimepicker/2.5.4/build/jquery.datetimepicker.min.css" />
<div id="content">
Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consetetur sadipscing elitr, sed diam nonumy eirmod tempor invidunt ut labore et dolore magna aliquyam erat, sed diam voluptua. At vero eos et accusam et justo duo dolores et ea rebum. Stet clita kasd gubergren, no sea takimata sanctus est Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consetetur sadipscing elitr, sed diam nonumy eirmod tempor invidunt ut labore et dolore magna aliquyam erat, sed diam voluptua. At vero eos et accusam et justo duo dolores et ea rebum. <br/>
<br/>Stet clita kasd gubergren, no sea takimata sanctus est Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet.Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consetetur sadipscing elitr, sed diam nonumy eirmod tempor invidunt ut labore et dolore magna aliquyam erat, sed diam voluptua. At vero eos et accusam et justo duo dolores et ea rebum. Stet clita kasd gubergren, no sea takimata sanctus est Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consetetur sadipscing elitr, sed diam nonumy eirmod tempor invidunt ut labore et dolore magna aliquyam erat, sed diam voluptua. At vero eos et accusam et justo duo dolores et ea rebum. Stet clita kasd gubergren, no sea takimata sanctus est Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet.<br/><br/>
<input id="datetimepicker1" type="text" value="2014/03/15 05:06"> not working: dateTimePicker<br/>
<input id="dt1" /> working: jqueryUI Datepicker<br/>
<br/>Stet clita kasd gubergren, no sea takimata sanctus est Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet.Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consetetur sadipscing elitr, sed diam nonumy eirmod tempor invidunt ut labore et dolore magna aliquyam erat, sed diam voluptua. At vero eos et accusam et justo duo dolores et ea rebum. Stet <br/><br/>
<input id="datetimepicker2" type="text" value="2014/03/15 05:06"> not working: dateTimePicker<br/>
clita kasd gubergren, no sea takimata sanctus est Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consetetur sadipscing elitr, sed diam nonumy eirmod tempor invidunt ut labore et dolore magna aliquyam erat, sed diam voluptua. At vero eos et accusam et justo duo dolores et ea rebum. Stet clita kasd gubergren, no sea takimata sanctus est Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet.<br/><br/>Stet clita kasd gubergren, no sea takimata sanctus est Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet.Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consetetur sadipscing elitr, sed diam nonumy eirmod tempor invidunt ut labore et dolore magna aliquyam erat, sed diam voluptua. At vero eos et accusam et justo duo dolores et ea rebum. Stet clita kasd gubergren, no sea takimata sanctus est Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consetetur sadipscing elitr, sed diam nonumy eirmod tempor invidunt ut labore et dolore magna aliquyam erat, sed diam voluptua. At vero eos et accusam et justo duo dolores et ea rebum. Stet clita kasd gubergren, no sea takimata sanctus est Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet.<br/><br/>Stet clita kasd gubergren, no sea takimata sanctus est Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet.Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consetetur sadipscing elitr, sed diam nonumy eirmod tempor invidunt ut labore et dolore magna aliquyam erat, sed diam voluptua. At vero eos et accusam et justo duo dolores et ea rebum. Stet clita kasd gubergren, no sea takimata sanctus est Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consetetur sadipscing elitr, sed diam nonumy eirmod tempor invidunt ut labore et dolore magna aliquyam erat, sed diam voluptua. At vero eos et accusam et justo duo dolores et ea rebum. Stet clita kasd gubergren, no sea takimata sanctus est Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet.<br/>
</div>
<br />
<br />
<br />
<br />
<br />
<br />
<br />
<br />
<br />
<br />
<br />
<br />
<br />
<br />
<br />
<br />
<br />
<br />
<br />
<br />
<br />
<br />
<br />
<br />
<br />
<br />
<br />
<br />
<br />
<br />
<br />
<br />
<br />
<br />
<br />
<br />
<br />
<br />
<br />
<br />
<br />
<br />
<br />
<br />
```

Comment: Thanks for digging so deep. It is working fine, also with the position but only if you have 1 element using datetimepicker so you can put the id of the input field into the "of" method.

But if you have more inputs all with the same class ".datetimepicker" it will always append to the first one. The event.target seems not giving the correct input field.

Comment: @Maaaark, check the update. Now support multiple datetimepickers

Comment: Awesome! Working as is should from the beginning. Thanks mate!

Answer (score 0):

```
<div class="well">
  <div id="datetimepicker1" class="input-append date">
    <input data-format="dd/MM/yyyy hh:mm:ss" type="text"></input>
    <span class="add-on">
      <i data-time-icon="icon-time" data-date-icon="icon-calendar">
      </i>
    </span>
  </div>
</div>
<script type="text/javascript">
  $(function() {
    $('#datetimepicker1').datetimepicker({
      language: 'pt-BR'
    });
  });
</script>
```

Comment: Sorry, but I don't know how this could solve the problem.

Comment: you are using bootstrap just copy the code and paste it in your project.

Comment: I don't see any bootstrap in my posted code ..
Your example only shows the datepicker in PT language and thats not what i was looking for.